# Error when creating 3D Surface plot with matplotlib

Tags: pandas, plotly-python

**Error**
 `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

I am trying to create a 3D Surface plot that I found here [Plotly Surface Plot with Categorical Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64436536/plotly-surface-plot-with-categorical-data) but I am running into the above error.

I would like Report date on the x-axis so the x-axis will go from 01-Jul-22 to 01-Nov-22.
The Y-Axis will contain the count of the changes and the Z-Axis will have the change type

My data looks like this:

[image]

**Code**

```
# grab x/y labels, create storage for z data
states = DF['Change Type'].unique()
states.sort()
weeks = DF['Report Date'].unique()
weeks.sort()
z_data = []

# extract z data using x,y coordinates within the dataframe
for week in weeks:
  row = []
  for state in states:
    val = DF[
      (DF['Change Type'] == state) &
      (DF['Report Date'] == week)]['Count of Changes'].values[0]
    row.append(val)
  z_data.append(row)


# create and show the Surface plot
trace = go.Surface(x=states, y=weeks, z=z_data)
data = [trace]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
fig.show()
```